# Javascript: Simulate PDF Print

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have an embedded PDF in my HTML.

```
<object id="myPDF" type="application/pdf" data="visual.pdf" style="width:500px; height:500px"></object>
```

This works perfectly, and the file is displayed on the page, along with the basic features such as "print", "save", etc.

Is there any way of providing `<input type="button" />` whose onclick function will invoke the "print" functionality of the embedded PDF? The reason for this is because I want to hide the  tag, and just provide a link or a button which will print the hidden document.

Answer (score 2):

put an iframe in html page.

include your pdf inside iframe.

Then which ever button click you want to show PDFs

```
onclick='window.open ("yourpdf.html","mywindow");'
```

after loading this page call   `window.print();`

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you could call some functions on the PDF reader with Javascript.  However, please don't do this.  Not everyone uses Adobe's Acrobat Reader to read PDFs.  Other readers won't support your code.  Because of this, it isn't possible.

Furthermore, it isn't advisable to use the `<object>` tag.  It is best to leave it up to the user, and give a simple link to the PDF.  Then it will work for anyone with a compatible reader.

Comment: This is just for an internal tool :-)

Comment: I have actually read about the obj.setActive(); obj.setFocus(); obj.print(). However when I tried that approach, I just kept on getting unknown function error.

Comment: Ah, well in that case, I would keep digging on that problem.  If you can get the `.print` function to work for you, that will fix it.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I am trying to do right now :-). Hopefully someone here has experienced the same problem, and would be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/reader_overview.pdf  Have you tried `.printAll()`?